# Mysql row and column transformation

Tags: mysql

I am working on a query on my sql where I have query :

```
SELECT particulars.particularName as name, particulars.Date as date, SUM(particulars.Total) as Total 
FROM particulars 
WHERE particulars.Date BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30' 
    AND particulars.Branch_BranchId='1'
GROUP by particulars.particularName,particulars.Date
```

The output is of the form ::
[image: current output]

But i need output in following format :
[image: Required output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is called pivoting.

Look on this example (you can find many on the web):

http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/